# /usr/lib/sys/sysinit is it a virus

Tags: apache-2.4, malware

i have a little experince in managiing debian server.
at the last few days i found a strange behaviour from my apache2 host web app
in term of failer to upload files with "UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: Missing a temporary folder" error with changing the tmp file permissions
also there are a strange crontab job named "*/3 * * * * bash /usr/lib/sys/sysinit  "
it keep reappering even after removing it .
so i think it is a virus or my server is hacked ...
any idea or advise insteed of making a complete re install
yours .
MOrabi